# Another solution to a simple DE given by DSolve: not the one I expected

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

Consider a simple 2nd-order differential equation with a parameter $a$, which can be solved with `DSolve`:

```
soly=DSolve[y''[x] + a/y[x]^3 == 0, y[x], x, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(*{{y[x] -> -(Sqrt[-a + x^2 C[1]^2 + 2 x C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/Sqrt[C[1]])},
  {y[x] -> Sqrt[-a + x^2 C[1]^2 + 2 x C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/Sqrt[C[1]]}}*)
```

I am interested in the one without the negative sign. It may be convenient to assign some simple values to the undetermined constants to observe the structure of the solution:

```
soly[[2, 1, 2]] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}
(*Sqrt[1 - a + 2 x + x^2]*)
```

That seems okay, but if one tries `y=a^1/4 * Sqrt[2 x]`, it also satisfies the equation.

```
y2[x] = a^(1/4)*Sqrt[2 x];
D[y2[x], {x, 2}]
(*-(a^(1/4)/(2 Sqrt[2] x^(3/2)))*)

a/y2[x]^3
(*a^(1/4)/(2 Sqrt[2] x^(3/2))*)
```

I am wondering how can I choose the different solutions, or if the solutions are basically equivalent to each other. In particular, the $a^{1/4}$ prefactor in the latter solution is very different (in the sense of structure) from the parameter $a$ under the square root in the `DSolve` solution. Can someone help me to understand the difference? Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you! i have tried to make the problem more clearly, please see my update.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had a typo in the code I tested.  I get the same thing you do.

Comment: @MichaelE2 hi, never mind, just hope someone can give a hint.

Comment: I can give a hint (I just haven't figured out the exact answer): Your answer seems to be a limiting case. Something like let $c_2 = \phi(c_1)$, for an appropriate function $\phi$ and take the limit as $c_1\rightarrow\infty$ or probably as $c_1 \rightarrow 0$. Or maybe yours is a singular solution, but my first inclination is not. I just haven't had time to work on it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Specifically, replace `C[2] -> Sqrt[a]/C[1]`, and take the limit as `C[1]` -> 0`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you for the suggestion. As mentioned by Michael the expected answer should be a solution in the limit of small `x`, for example, `x<<1`. But, even with this condition, how did you figure out the relation between the two constants? And how did you then deduce that we should take the limit `C1->0`? brilliant

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes, the expected solution is a singular one: as `x->0`, `y->0`, so the 2nd term blows up. How can we deduce such a relation between c2 and c1, should I figure out a boundary condition?

Comment: I determined that `C[1] -> 0` was the correct limit by solving the ODE using `Integrate` instead of `DSolve` to obtain both solutions in your question.  Then, I expanded the general solution as a power series in `C[1]` and chose a value for `C[2]` that cancelled the leading term.  I can write this up as an answer, if that would be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, please elaborate, I believe such a method might shed light on a general kind of approach for solving such kind of nonlinear ODE with singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my earlier comments on the question, a first integral of the ODE can be obtained by

```
eq = y''[x] + a/y[x]^3;
s1 = Simplify[2 Integrate[eq y'[x], x]] == C[1]
(* -(a/y[x]^2) + y'[x]^2 == C[1] *)
```

`DSolve` applied to the equation then yields the two general solutions given in the question, plus two equivalent solutions.  And, setting `C[1]` to zero yields

```
DSolve[s1 /. C[1] -> 0, y[x], x] /. C[1] -> C[2]
(* {{y[x] -> -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-Sqrt[a] x + C[2]]}, 
    {y[x] -> Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-Sqrt[a] x + C[2]]}, 
    {y[x] -> -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[a] x + C[2]]}, 
    {y[x] -> Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[a] x + C[2]]}} *)
```

the last of which is an obvious generalization of the special solution given in the question.  It follows that the special solution is related to the general solution by taking the limit `C[1] -> 0`.

Next, use `Integrate` again to obtain

```
MultiplySides[Last@Last@Solve[s1, y'[x]] /. Rule -> Equal, 
    y[x]/Sqrt[a + C[1] y[x]^2], Assumptions -> y[x] != 0]
(* (y[x] y'[x])/Sqrt[a + C[1] y[x]^2] == 1 *)
Integrate[Subtract @@ %, x] - C[2]
(* -x - C[2] + Sqrt[a + C[1] y[x]^2]/C[1] *)
```

which can be solved for `y[x]` to obtain the general solutions given above and in the question.  Instead, expand this expression about `C[1] = 0`

```
Series[%, {C[1], 0, 0}] // Normal
(* -x + Sqrt[a]/C[1] - C[2] + y[x]^2/(2 Sqrt[a]) *)
```

and redefine `C[2]` (an arbitray constant) to explicitly eliminate `Sqrt[a]/C[1]`, i.e., `C[2] -> C[2] + Sqrt[a]/C[1]`.

```
Simplify[y[x] /. soly[[2]] /. C[2] -> C[2] + Sqrt[a]/C[1]]
(* Sqrt[C[1] (x + C[2]) (2 Sqrt[a] + C[1] (x + C[2]))]/Sqrt[C[1]] *)
```

where `soly` is defined in the question.  Finally, taking the limit, `C[1] -> 0`, yields the desired outcome.

```
Series[%, {C[1], 0, 0}] // Normal
(* Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[a] (x + C[2])] *)
```

Comment: in your answer you have explained clearly why we should take the limit `C[1] -> 0` by finding the general sol from an equivalent DE, which is obtained by `Integrate` once. Then, you used `Solve` to obtain y'[x] and `Integrate` once to find an implicit expression for `y`. Next, you expand the implicit expression at `C[1]=0`, as required. From here, we can find a value of `C[2]` to eliminate `Sqrt[a]/C[1]` at the leading order. But, there seems some errors in the next 2 steps ...

Comment: @Enter What are those errors?

Comment: should we use `soly[[4]]` in the 2nd code-line from the bottom?

Comment: @Enter.  Actually, neither one.  I meant the `soly` that you defined in your question.  I have made a few changes to my answer to eliminate this ambiguity.  Thanks for pointing it out.